# Find CATALINA Tomcat8

Tags: security, tomcat8, audit, rhel7, catalina

I've been working on auditing using CIS Benchmarks
for example :

[root@localhost ~]# ls -l $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/docs \

> CATALINA_HOME/webapps/examples
>   ls: cannot access /webapps/docs: No such file or directory
>   ls: cannot access CATALINA_HOME/webapps/examples: No such file or directory

The thing is every command includes "CATALINA" and I've been trying my best to find that directory but seems like it doesnt exist.
Can anyone tell me how to install tomcat 8 'n RHEL7 ? And how to find that "CATALINA" container..

Answer (score 0):

Normally it can be found in your tomcat installation directory -> work -> Catalina

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@localhost log]# cd tomcat
[root@localhost tomcat]# ls
catalina.2018-02-26.log   host-manager.2018-02-26.log
catalina.out              localhost.2018-02-26.log
catalina.out-20180226.gz  localhost_access_log.2018-02-26.txt
catalina.out-20180305.gz  manager.2018-02-26.log
[root@localhost tomcat]#
```

Here s what I found

Answer (score 0):

It's okay I kind of understood that "CATALINA_HOME" was nothing but the directory where tomcat has been installed
and in my case the equivalent of "CATALINA_HOME" is "usr/share/tomcat"